# Where is htmlAttribute at ASP.NET Core <a>?

Tags: asp.net-core

I would like to insert `htmlAttribute` to the following code

```html
<a asp-action="MyTestAction" asp-controller="Home" asp-route-myid1="a" asp-route-myid2="b">Test</a>
```

as there is at `@Html.ActionLink`:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a tag helper.

With tag helpers, you insert attributes directly into the view body as raw HTML attributes:

```html
<a asp-action="MyTestAction"
   asp-controller="Home"
   asp-route-myid1="a"
   asp-route-myid2="b"
   class="foo"
   disabled
   data-whatever="@razor_expression">Test</a>
```